# Lambda-Expression compiler code generation

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, language-design

The following C# code containing lambda expressions

```cs
public class MeClass 
{
    public void Main() 
    {
        Func<int> func = () => 12;
    }    
}
```

is lowered by the compiler to

```cs
public class MeClass
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Func<int> <>9__0_0;

        internal int <Main>b__0_0()
        {
            return 12;
        }
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        Func<int> func = <>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Func<int>(<>c.<>9.<Main>b__0_0));
    }
}
```

Generated by https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgASwwWQKYDCANgIYDOZGyA3shvVplACy4kCWAdgBQCUVSBhlqChDKAFYAPFwAuAPgwAzAK6cAxhgC8GPtsVwYAbjoMAvkORmgA=.

I understand that my delegate instance `Func<int> func` will be initialized with the value of the field `Func<int> <>9__0_0` in `<>c`.
This field will be initialized when `Func<int> func` is initialized.
My question is, why `<>c` has a field of the same delegate type in the first place.
Why is the value of `Func<int> func` not directly set to `new Func<int>(<>c.<>9.<Main>b__0_0)`?
I'm guessing, that `Func<int> <>9__0_0` can somehow be reused, but I wasn't able to reproduce how.

Comment: It's called [lowering](https://mattwarren.org/2017/05/25/Lowering-in-the-C-Compiler/)

Comment: @orhtej2 Awesome, wasn't able to find somehow, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `<c>.<>9__0_0` is a cache. Think about what happens if you call `Main()` twice: `<c>.<>9__0_0` is only assigned on the first call, and it already has a value on subsequent calls. This avoids creating loads of new unnecessary delegate instances

Comment: That totally makes sence! Thank you, somehow didn't think of that.